# Elasticsearch-7.8.1 is intermittently showing random suggestions during phrase suggestion

Tags: elasticsearch, autosuggest, search-suggestion, phrase

I've an Elasticsearch-7.8.1 running in 3-node cluster setup. I use a match query on fields along with phrase suggester for querying the documents across multiple indices.

Now coming to the problem, whenever I use the above mentioned match query to search for a matching document with exact spelling of the document which is present in my elasticsearch the phrase suggester part shows me some random suggestion and the suggestion that I get is intermittent for same input text.

For eg,
Lets say I have some 3-4 documents indexed like ***Bills***, ***How do I do Bill Pay*** ,***What is the status of Bill payment***, ***What are the benefits of bigger Bill payments ?***

My query is as follows:

```
GET idx-name1,idx-name2/_search
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field1": "bill pay"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "field2": "bill pay"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "suggest": {
    "text": "bill pay",
    "YOUR_SUGGESTION": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "field1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:
I intermittently get suggestion as **"bigg pay"** in phrase suggester part.

Please help me, this is acting as a barrier for me in creating 'Did you mean functionality ?'

Comment: are you using a n-gram token filter on field1?

Comment: @Nate. How do i check that ? I'm new to elasticsearch

Comment: use `GET index-name/_mapping/field/field1`

Comment: No there is no n-gram token filter

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information to debug your issue, but few pointers so that you can debug it yourself or provide the information so that we can help you further.

1. Provide your index mapping and setting, please refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html) to know how to get it
2. Use [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to see how your search is woking under the hood.

Comment: is this an answer?